# How to add additional fields to user documents (not in profile)?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

I know that the classic way to add data to user collection is in `profile` array, but according to [this document](https://meteor.hackpad.com/Proposal-for-deprecating-user-profile-3UljX1VayvV), it is not the best way to store data.

Is there an alternative to that, for example to create a field in the root of user collection at the same level with default fields (`_id`, `username`, etc.)?

Comment: Yes, you can create your custom fields and publish them on demand, or disallow the free editing of the profile field (recommended anyway).

Comment: Thanks MasterAM, Can you give more detail about how to create a custom field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong per-se with the `profile` field, other than the fact that a users can (currently) directly update their own profile by default.

I don't find this behavior desired, as a user could store arbitrary data in the profile.

This may become a real security risk if the developer uses that field as a source of authority; for example, stores the user's groups or roles in it.

In this case, users could set their own permissions and roles.

This is caused by [this code](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js#L1393):

```js
users.allow({
  // clients can modify the profile field of their own document, and
  // nothing else.
  update: function (userId, user, fields, modifier) {
    // make sure it is our record
    if (user._id !== userId)
      return false;

    // user can only modify the 'profile' field. sets to multiple
    // sub-keys (eg profile.foo and profile.bar) are merged into entry
    // in the fields list.
    if (fields.length !== 1 || fields[0] !== 'profile')
      return false;

    return true;
  }
});
```

The first thing to do is to restrict writes to it:

```js
Meteor.users.deny({
  update() {
    return true;
  }
});
```

It could then be updated using methods and other authorized code.

If you add your own fields and want to publish them to the currently logged-in user, you can do so by using an automatic publication:

```js
Meteor.publish(null, function () {
  if (this.userId) {
    return Meteor.users.find({
      _id: this.userId
    }, {
      fields: {
        yourCustomField1: 1,
        yourCustomField2: 1
      }
    });
  } else {
    return this.ready();
  }
});
```

`Meteor.users` is just a normal `Mongo.Collection`, so modifying it is done just like any other Collection. There is also the creation hook, `Accounts.onCreateUser` which allows you to add custom data to the user object when it is first created, as mentioned in @MatthiasEckhart's answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You could add extra fields to user documents via the [`accountsServer.onCreateUser(func)`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser) function.

For example:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
        _.extend(user, {
            myValue: "value",
            myArray: [],
            myObject: {
                key: "value"
            }
        });
    });
}
```

**Please note:** By default, the following [`Meteor.users`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_users) fields are published to the client `username`, `emails` and `profile`. As a consequence, you need to publish any additional fields.

For instance:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish("user", function() {
        if (this.userId) return Meteor.users.find({
            _id: this.userId
        }, {
            fields: {
                'myValue': 1,
                'myArray': 1,
                'myObject': 1
            }
        });
        else this.ready();
    });
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.subscribe("user");
}
```

Comment: This aproch is working for the user.profile.myValue, but not for user.myValue, or it is something else that I am missing?

Comment: This approach adds additional fields to user documents at root level. Could you please share a [MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com)?

Comment: "http://meteorpad.com/pad/YtdfK7CnSbZFbeWzu/Copy%20of%20Leaderboard"
I get "Internal server error".

Comment: You need to return the (modified) user document. Here's the updated [MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/dNqzjX36bG2fHuvtE/Leaderboard-Accounts-Extend-User-Document).

Comment: My mistake when copying to meteorpad, 
the point is that the new field did not appear in DB, I put the printscreen(Mongol), to be more clear:


http://imageshack.com/a/img910/811/cwkHCt.png

The same effect I get on the claud host.

Comment: You need to publish the additional fields, that's why you can't access them on the client.